# Why do I get Method definition for ... not found error after refactoring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, header, warnings

I have a very small class with an `enum` in the `.h` file, and that's it. I recently refactored the name of the `.h` file and for some reason the `.m` file names didn't refactor, so I had to change it manually. Now everything works as intended, but I suddenly get a warning on my `@implementation` in my `.m` file: `Method definition for ... not found`. Not sure why.

It looks like this in `.m`:

```
#import "TabTypeEnum.h"

@interface TabTypeEnum ()

@end

@implementation TabTypeEnum

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

and in the `.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface TabTypeEnum : UIViewController

typedef enum {
    MyTravels = 0,
    Excursions,
    Experiences,
    Map,
    Discover
} MyTabType;

- (void)myTabFunc: (MyTabType) myTab;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

I didn't get the warning before, and all I did was change all the names to `TabTypeEnum`. I don't want to have the method implemented in the `.m` file. It's fine as it is.

Comment: You've defined `- (void)myTabFunc:` in the .h without implementing it in the .m Adding an implementation of that method to the .m should get rid of the warning

Comment: Yes, but before refactoring it I hadn't implemented it in the .m file yet I didn't get a warning. Also there is no reason for it to be implemented in the .m file. Is it fine if I just remove the .m file?